# Android notify in dark mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When I use dark mode, the active notification on the android taskbar does not change the color of the text. This makes it very bad to see what is written. Is there a way to define a color for light and dark mode within the layout XML, without changing the theme?

Comment: Notifications using the default templates automatically update. Are you using a custom template / style for your notification that is setting a fixed color? Please include your code.

Comment: Does All notification not change color of text in Dark Mode?